# Can I replace a set of 215/60R16 tires with a set of 205/55R16 (all four tires)? Toyota camry

Tags: toyota, tires, replacements

Can I replace a set of 215/60R16 tires with a set of 205/55R16 (all four tires)? Toyota Camry

I have read other post asking a similar question and some people have said that the spedometer may be affected when downsizing a set of tires is there anything else I should be worried about?

I have a Toyota Camry with 215/60R16 tires they all need to be changed, and I have four 205/55R16 tires from a Pontiac G5 which are new, can I put the 205/55R16 tires on the Camry?

I know that most mechanics will suggest to replace with the manufacturer recommended size but this would save me at least $800 if I use the 205/55R16 that I already have.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Where on earth are you shopping that is quoting $800 for a set of 215/60/16s??

Comment: I'm in Quebec Canada and new tires would considerably more than $800. But that's Canadian dollars so more like $600 USD. @3Dave

Comment: Do you know if changing tires from 215/60R16 to 205/55R16 is OK?@3Dave

Comment: *I* wouldn't put a 215 on a rim intended for a 205, but I'm picky. It'll probably be fine.

Comment: @3Dave Wheels don't have a section width spec. They might have a manufacturer recommended maximum, but I've never run across a tire I couldn't get mounted on a wheel, as long as the rim was correct. The sidewall will squish to where it needs to be.

Comment: If you are going to play with tire sizes a bit, you need to move one number up and the other number down. You cannot move both up or down without drastically changing the tire diameter. In this case, going from 215/60 to 205/55 will make a smaller tire. If you go from 215/60 to 225/55, that will be roughly the same, but I don't think 215/55 is a common size. Alternatively, you could go from 215/60 to 205/65. That would close too. You can bump section width 10, but then you need to bump ratio 5 in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful resource here:

[Tire Size Calculator](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

Yes, that smaller size should work and yes, your speedo will read a bit higher than it should due to the smaller diameter of the tires.